# Why is there a splitter, "LO" source, and two identical sections in a network analyzer?

Tags: network

I am taking the Keysight *Network Analyzer* course. In the diagram below, there is a splitter and two identical sections in the network analyzer circuit.

Why is there a splitter and two parts which look exactly the same? What does the "LO" source in the middle of the circuit do?

[image]

Comment: LO - Local oscillator.

Answer (score 1):

The LO is the local oscillator, used as a reference frequency for downconversion in the mixers contained within the two measurement receivers. It drives two sections, one for each port of the DUT (device under test). A four-port network analyzer will have more ports.

The use of a mixer allows one to determine phase, rather than simply measuring received power like a spectrum analyzer would.

Each section now consists of a reference receiver, a measurement receiver, a directional coupler (blue rectangle), and a connection to the device under test. The source is applied to either the upper or the lower network; it is split using the splitter to the reference receiver (to measure the applied signal precisely) and to the DUT via the directional coupler. The directional coupler transmits most<sup>1</sup> of the source power to the DUT, and a small coupled portion is discarded in a matched load (resistor symbol).

The DUT has certain reflection (i.e. \$S_{11}\$, \$S_{22}\$) and transmission coefficients (i.e. \$S_{12}\$, \$S_{21}\$) which are to be measured. The directional power returning from the two ports on the DUT enters the network analyzer, and a small<sup>1</sup> portion of the returning power is coupled to the measurement receiver through the directional coupler.

In order to yield measurements of the DUT, the measured power at the receivers is corrected by the VNA calibration and by the actual measurement made at the reference receiver.

<sup>1</sup> These and other losses and phase shifts in the system (including ones from your own testbench cabling) must be corrected for, which is why VNAs are to be calibrated, e.g. using a kit of precision shorts/opens/matches.

Answer (score 1):

The splitter is there so that you can measure the characteristics of the source, and then cal-out (subtract) the source characteristics, such as phase and amplitude ripple, from your measurement.  Without the ability to do that, you would not be able to separate the response of the test set from that of the DUT.